# How to select and sub-select from 2 tables?

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I have 2 tables as below:

Table1:

```
variable    value
--------------------------------------------
app1        name@email.com, name2@email.com
app2        name3@email.com, name4@email.com
```

Table2:

```
app DatabaseName    server
---------------------------
app1    DB1        server1
app1    DB1        server2
app2    DB2        server1
app2    DB2        server3
```

I want to select the the email recipients from the value column in Table1 for which DatabaseName is 'DB1' in Table2.

The expected results are: name@email.com, name2@email.com.

How can I do that?

Basically the tricky part here is that the column name is not "app" in Table1, but rather "variable". It is the requirement that way, So how do I achieve selecting email recipients for a databaseName based on the classified app the DatabaseName belongs to in Table2 and matches in Table1?

Comment: You need to `JOIN` the two tables `ON App = Variables`? Your question is a bit confusing.

Comment: This sounds like a basic join. I think you are hung up on the column names not being the same. There is no reason you have to have the same column names in a join.

Comment: @SeanLange yep i think i was overcomplicating it due to the column name difference. somehow it seemed easy but i just couldnt put my finger on it

Comment: @Sami i couldnt paraphrase the title to what i wanted exactly. the answers though are perfect for what i need. it is a join afterall that i needed, but seemed i was overcomplicating it due to column name differences. do you recommend a better title for this thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do a join.

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.[value] 
FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN Table2 T2 
ON T1.[variable] = T2.[APP] 
WHERE T2.DatabaseName = 'DB1'
```

Comment: shouldnt Table2 be mentioned somewhere for the T2 alias?

Comment: Yes I just fixed.

Comment: thak you so much. these answers are perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the tables:

```
select distinct t1.*
from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2
on t2.app = t1.variable
where t2.databasename = 'DB1'
```

I used `distinct` because from your sample data there are 2 rows for `databasename = 'DB1'` and otherwise you would get the same row twice.

Comment: perfect answer but i had to accept Flavino's since he answered first. Thanks for your guidance on this!I think i was over-complicating it in my mind due to column name differences